failed to read dockerfile when starting ollama
Hello i installed docker on opensuse and then i tried running ollama via docker compose.
However i get a strange error.
Any help please ?

my yaml file
Here is my yml file
version: '3.6'
services:
  ollama:
    volumes:
      - ollama:/root/.ollama
    # Uncomment below to expose Ollama API outside the container stack
    # ports:
    #   - 11434:11434
    container_name: ollama
    pull_policy: always
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: ollama/ollama:latest
  ollama-webui:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        OLLAMA_API_BASE_URL: '/ollama/api'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: ollama-webui:latest
    container_name: ollama-webui
    depends_on:
      - ollama
    ports:
      - 3000:8080
    environment:
      - "OLLAMA_API_BASE_URL=http://ollama:11434/api"
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  ollama: {}


Hi @ramstein, it would be very useful if you provide your Dockerfiles and docker-compose YAML files to have better insight of what you are tryig to do.

The image helps. Indeed, docker-compose is not finding a Dockerfile within the folder .../tmp/buildkit-mount... . This file is necessary to mount your app container.

just posted the content from docker-compose.yml

Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the {} button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.

@ramstein I went forward on your code and I guess you are using the code shared at ollama-docker -or something similar for ollama.
Indeed, there is another .YAML file to run this code with docker-compose app. Please, verify whether you have a YAML named as docker-compose-ollama-gpu.yaml in your project. If so, you can run it as explained in the Starting Guide. Note that it is different if you want to run it when GPU is configured.

with or without the gpu it returns the same error

Probably, your ollama starting project is corrupted. You can get the ollama-docker project from Github and use the steps in the Configuration. I just tried and it worked well. Note that it will run faster if you can get GPU support. If so, you can run it with the alterative .yaml file as below:
docker-compose -f docker-compose-ollama-gpu.yaml up -d


That is where i get the docker-compose.yml file. So i guess its something about my docker instalaton...

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include details like the terminal output in plain text?  You don't seem to have included the actual Compose file here; if the asker doesn't already have the docker-compose-ollama-gpu.yaml file, what changes should they make in their setup?

@ramstein, If you are doing the setup of your ollama in OpenSuse I suggest to double-check the steps to install Docker in OpenSUSE. Note that there is a user having trouble with docker-compose in the Discussion section of this post. Probably you also need a workaround to install docker-compose in OpenSUSE. Besides, there is another page where OpenSUSE community shares a docker-compose download. However, "[these] distributions are not officially supported."
